# Powershell multiple matching in get-content

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I want to see if there are any lines containing the word "Newer" and/or "New File".  I have tried script like below but no luck. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
RoboCopy.exe  "C:\Folder" "C:\Folder2" *.* /S /E /MIR /MT:8 /X /V /TS /FP /BYTES /ETA /LOG:C:\Output\log\sync.txt

$SourceDir = "C:\Output\log\"
#$GCI_Fiter = '*.txt'
$Include=@("*.txt")

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Include "$Include" -File
foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)   {

$results = Get-Content -Path $FL_Item.FullName | Select-String -pattern '(newer.New File)'

}
```

Robocopy log :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Wednesday, December 25, 2019 8:16:28 PM
   Source : C:\Folder\
     Dest : C:\Folder2\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /V /X /TS /FP /BYTES /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /ETA /MT:8 /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        New File               1 2019/12/25 17:16:04    C:\Folder\2.txt
              same             0 2019/12/25 11:38:23    C:\Folder\2\1.txt
              same            24 2019/09/25 08:42:17    C:\Folder\5.csv
        Newer                  1 2019/12/25 17:16:04    C:\Folder\4.txt
100%  
              same             0 2019/12/11 08:06:39    C:\Folder\1.txt
              same             0 2019/12/11 08:06:39    C:\Folder\2.txt


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

if you load that file into `$InStuff` with `Get-Content`, you can use the way that `-match` works on a collection. that will give you the lines that match the regex pattern. like this ...

```
$InStuff -match 'newer|new file'
```

output ...

```
New File               1 2019/12/25 17:16:04    C:\Folder\2.txt
Newer                  1 2019/12/25 17:16:04    C:\Folder\4.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6)'s `-Path` parameter takes an array, you don't need a loop. If we use [Glenn's helpful regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59484030/11025476), you can do the following:

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Include $Include -File
$results = Select-String -Path $FileList -Pattern '^\s+(Newer|New File)'
```

**Explanation:**

`$results` will contain `MatchInfo` objects if any matches are found. The default display of those results will be the relative path of the file with the match, the match's line number, and the matched line. However, you have access to properties to easily tailor the output differently. See below for how to view the available properties:

```
$results[0] | Get-Member -MemberType Property

   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name       MemberType Definition
----       ---------- ----------
Context    Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename   Property   string Filename {get;}
IgnoreCase Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}
Line       Property   string Line {get;set;}
LineNumber Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}
Matches    Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
Path       Property   string Path {get;set;}
Pattern    Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
```

See below for examples of how to use the properties:

```
# List Unique Files That Contain a Match
$results.Path | Get-Unique

# List All File Paths and Their Matching Lines
$results | Select-Object Path,Line

# Default Display
# Format Is RelativePath:LineNumber:Line
$results

# Calculated Properties Including Log File Path, Newer or New File as Type, the Copied File
$results | select Path,
                  @{n='Type';e={$_.Matches.Groups[1]}},
                  @{n='Copied File';e={$_.Line -replace '.*\d+:\d+:\d+\s+'}}
```

**Regex Details:**

`^\s+(Newer|New File)`:

- `^`: Start of a string, which means the start of each line here.
- `\s+`: `\s` is a white space character. `+` is one or more matches. So this represents one or more consecutive white spaces.
- `(Newer|New File)`: `|` is the regex `or` assertion. This will match `Newer` or `New File`. Using the `()` ensures that the previous `^\s+` is matched first. Without `()`, `^\s+Newer` or `New File` is applied. It does create an unnecessary capture group though. `(?:Newer|New File)` is the non-capturing version.

Answer (score 0):

This will return `$true` if there are *.txt files with `Newer` or `New File` at the beginning of the line (so that it doesn't also show false positives for filenames that might container `Newer` in their name.)

```
(Get-ChildItem *.txt | Select-String -Pattern "^\s+(Newer|New File)" | Measure-Object).Count -gt 0
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks but I dont understand your regex expression. could you please clarify me ?

Comment: @Arbelac, `^` means start of a line, `\s` is a white space character, `+` is one or more times (white space repeating indefinitely), then either the string `Newer` or `New File`. The `|` means *or*. The `()` is just a grouping mechanism allowing the entire left hand side (LHS) of the `|` and the entire RHS of the `|` to be checked within the `()`.

Comment: Thanks @AdminOfThings.  @Arbelac, I'm assuming that was your intent when using `(newer.New File)`?

Answer (score 0):

It can be as easy as giving select-string an array of patterns:

```
'newer','new file' | select-string newer,'new file'

newer
new file
```